# How can you increase the temperature of a fixed amount of gas by increasing the volume of the container?

Tags: pressure, temperature, ideal-gas

You have a fixed amount of gas. How can you increase its temperature **T** by increasing the container's volume **V** while keeping the pressure **P** constant? Technically, it can be done when considering,

> pV=nRT

But how can you do this with actual experimental set-ups?

Comment: It cant be done. If you increase the container's volume, then the pressure of the gas goes down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it by heating the gas. If you consider the gas in a cylinder where the piston applies constant pressure, then by heating the gas, the volume will expand while the pressure stays the same.

However, if you want to do it without adding energy, the energy conservation law prohibits it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vasily Mitch has already pointed out you do it by heating the gas under constant external pressure. But for the gas temperature to be constant you have to heat the gas extremely  slowly (reversibly) in order for the gas to always be in equilibrium with the external pressure. You do this by using a heat source whose temperature is always infinitesimally greater than the gas temperature.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply Heat to the system but slowly.

According to the 1st law of thermodynamics,

> dQ=dU+dW  
>  where, dW=pdV 
>  by plugin, 
>  dQ= dU+ p dV

dV is the change to the volume and the change is tends to zero.

Pressure and the quantity of gas will be constant. So it can be an **Isobaric process**. At first the internal energy of the system will increase through Isochoric process. Then the Volume V increases a little bit. So the pressure remains constant.